# iOS app has issues saying "Too many symbol files"

Tags: ios, binary, app-store-connect

When I submitted my app I'm getting following issue. What could be the exact reason ?
Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in any binary [C81A6D1A-8A74-3F1D-9B89-29C6E12B9FD4.symbols]

NOTE:-I have used Alamofire and WindowsAzure Messaging SDK as libraries.

Comment: I think this relates to building with debugging information turned on.

Comment: @Droppy how can i turn it off. Is it possible.

Comment: You need to examine your build settings.